# 'requests' distribution not found when listed in install_requires together with requests_oauthlib

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, setuptools

I have a setup.py file for a python package and when I try to run `python setup.py develop` it gets stuck on installing the `requests` package, apparently because of `requests_oauthlib` also being a requirement.  The following minimal example setup.py file still results in the same error:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='fakepackage',
    install_requires=[
        'requests_oauthlib',
        'requests',
    ]
)
```

The error is "error: The 'requests' distribution was not found and is required by fakepackage".  This happens regardless of the order in which I list the elements of the install_requires list.

If I run `pip install requests` manually, it installs fine, so I'm not sure what it's not finding.  If I don't list `requests` at all in the setup.py file, and only list `requests_oauthlib`, it also installs fine (including installing `requests`, which is a dependency of `requests_oauthlib`).

I'm using Python 3.8, setuptools version 44.0.0.